# How can I get documentation for the LaTeX letter class?

Tags: document-classes, documentation, texdoc

I am trying out TeX and writing some correspondence in it just to learn the basic commands. For the "letter" document class, I have found this reference site:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Letters

My question, put simply, is as follows:

- How do I get *documentation** on a particular document class, in this case: "letter"?

(*) By documentation I mean: "list of all commands, their syntax and usage"

Note: I can use

```
texdoc "packagename"
```

for packages but I don't know how to do the same for document classes?

Bonus/optional complement to this question (feel free to disregard it if you dislike multiple questions in a single post): where do I get a list of document classes from? (I get my list of packages from: http://ctan.org/pkg)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
texdoc letter
```

If you still need more information you can try

```
texdoc -l letter
```

Which gives you a longer list of related documentation. Even more can be obtained by typing

```
texdoc -s letter
```

You will get any documentation with a "letter" somewhere in the name or description with the latter.

Depending on the country your're in other non-standard letter classes fit much better. In Europe  for instance I would recommend `scrlttr2`

Edit (added from comment): there are differences between the unix based `texdoc` and MiKTeXs `texdoc`. In MiKTeX `texdoc` Option `-s` is not working.

Comment: A similar tool is available online: www.texdoc.net/pkg/letter

Comment: @doncherry This URL seems dead now, but I managed to the doc at the following one : [https://texdoc.org/pkg/letter](https://texdoc.org/pkg/letter).